# cant fill smart menu jquery grid with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I am using this [grid](http://www.smartmenus.org/docs/)

and i want to fill it with my data. Here is my code:

```js
 {"menu" :[{ 
"name": "Computers",
 "children": [{
  "name": "Notebook",
  "children": [{
   "name": "Apple"
  }, {
   "name": "Windows"
  }]
 }, {
  "name": "Tablets",
  "children": [{
   "name": "Apple"
  }, {
   "name": "Android"
  }, {
   "name": "Windows"
  }]
 }]
}, {
 "name": "Phones",
 "children": [{
  "name": "Android",
  "children": [{
   "name": "Samsung"
  }, {
   "name": "Nokia"
  }, {
   "name": "Lenovo"
  }]
 }, {
  "name": "Windows Phones",
  "children": [{
   "name": "Microsoft"
  }, {
   "name": "Nokia"
  }]
 }]
}, {
 "name": "Cameras",
 "children": [{
  "name": "Digital",
  "children": [{
   "name": "Nikon"
  }, {
   "name": "Fuji"
  }]
 }, {
  "name": "DSLR",
  "children": [{
   "name": "Canon"
  }, {
   "name": "Nikon"
  }]
 }]
}]
}




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#main-menu').smartmenus({
     subMenusSubOffsetX:1,
     subMenusSubOffsetY: -8
     
    });
  });   
</script>

 <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
 
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $.ajax({
              url: 'menuData.json',
              type: 'get',
              dataType: 'json',
              error: function(data){
               alert("error");
              },
              success: function(data){
               var obj=data;
               var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
               var s = JSON.parse(json);
               for(var i=0;i<s.menu.length;i++){
              for(var j=0;j<s.menu[i].children.length;j++)
              for(var n=0;n<s.menu[i].children[j].children.length;n++){
              
              
                $("#main-menu2").append('<li><span>' + s.menu[i].name+s.menu[i].children[j].name + s.menu[i].children[j].children[n].name + '</span></li>');
              
               }
               }
                  }
              });

         });
      </script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Mobile menu toggle button (hamburger/x icon) -->
<input id="main-menu-state" type="checkbox" />
<label class="main-menu-btn" for="main-menu-state">
  <span class="main-menu-btn-icon"></span> Toggle main menu visibility
</label>

<!-- Sample menu definition -->

<nav id="main-nav" role="navigation">

     <ul id="main-menu2" class="sm sm-clean"></ul>
 

</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

It prints the data in the screen without filling the menu.

ERROR:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in contentscript.js:21

I am a beginner so thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have an error in your console?

Comment: yes .. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in contentscript.js:21

Comment: add jquery to your project

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
var data = {
  "menu": [{
    "name": "Computers",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Notebook",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Apple"
      }, {
        "name": "Windows"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Tablets",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Apple"
      }, {
        "name": "Android"
      }, {
        "name": "Windows"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Phones",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Android",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Samsung"
      }, {
        "name": "Nokia"
      }, {
        "name": "Lenovo"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Windows Phones",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Microsoft"
      }, {
        "name": "Nokia"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Cameras",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Digital",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Nikon"
      }, {
        "name": "Fuji"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "DSLR",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Canon"
      }, {
        "name": "Nikon"
      }]
    }]
  }]
};


var obj = data;
var menu ='';
$.each(data.menu,function(i,v){
menu += '<li>'+v.name+'<ul>';
  $.each(v.children,function(x,t){
    menu += '<li>'+t.name+'<ul>';
    $.each(t.children,function(j,r){
     menu+='<li>'+r.name+'</li>';
    });
    menu += '</ul></li>';
  });
menu += '</ul></li>';
});
  $("#main-menu2").append(menu);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Mobile menu toggle button (hamburger/x icon) -->
<input id="main-menu-state" type="checkbox" />
<label class="main-menu-btn " for="main-menu-state">
  <span class="main-menu-btn-icon "></span> Toggle main menu visibility
</label>

<!-- Sample menu definition -->

<nav id="main-nav" role="
navigation ">

  <ul id="main-menu2" class="sm sm-clean "></ul>


</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much says it all. `$` is not defined. I would think that you did not link jQuery to the page, but you mentioned you already did that. So, two possibilities remain:

- You might be loading jquery AFTER you try to use `$` and at the point you try to use `$` it is not defined YET
- Your jquery object might have a different name from `$`, like `jQuery`, for example